# What kind of server can be accessed at \\SERVERNAME in Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, home-server, ubuntu-server

I want to have Ubuntu running a server that I can access from my Windows machine using \SERVERNAME\LOCATION. What kind of server do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to run a Samba server on the Ubuntu machine, and you'll need to configure Samba to share out the directories that you want available.